# Grabbing information from different websites

Tags: php, wordpress

Am currently working on a website ( http://durbeenoman.com ).
I'm trying to use a plugin that grabs specific information from different websites and list them into my website.
Any idea of a way or a plugin does such a job ?

Thanks

Comment: Such thing is called a webscraper

Comment: @NielsDrost awesome, i spent a lot searching for this 
any recommended plugins ? i found this, it should do the job right ? 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-web-scrapper/

Comment: @NielsDrost is there a plugin that grabs info from multi-sites ?

Comment: to who ever interested, this might be helpful, trying it right now http://www.supraliminalsolutions.com/blog/supra-scraper-tutorials/

Comment: I use http://scrapy.org/ myself, but is in Python

Comment: @NielsDrost can u use it on wordpress? how ?

Comment: and is it updatable ?